# Facebook: How to remove image associated with a share URL

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-graph-api, share

An `og:image` tag was previously placed on a page/URL that was shared to Facebook like this:

`<meta property="og:image" content="{image-url}" />`

Facebook has cached this tag associated with the URL.  Now I'd like to ask Facebook to forget about that image.  I've removed that tag from the URL, but when I ask Facebook to rescrape that URL using the Graph Object Debugger (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/), it correctly can't find the `og:image` tag, but chooses to keep using the previously cached image.  This is the message I see from their object debugger:

> og:image was not defined, could not be downloaded or was not big
>   enough. Please define a chosen image using the og:image metatag, and
>   use an image that's at least 200x200px and is accessible from
>   Facebook. Image
>   '{previously cached image}'
>   will be used instead. Consult
>   http://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler for
>   more troubleshooting tips.

Is there a way to tell Facebook to forget about an outdated `og:image` tag?

Comment: Only by explicitly specifying a new one.

Comment: @CBroe: that's the only thing that's worked for me as well.  I ended up specifying a small white image, which isn't great, but does clear the previous image.